Showing the Graph of a Projective Transformation is Intersection of a Quadric Surface and a Plane
I'm trying to do Exercise 3.6 at the end of this pdf:


Let $\tau: P^1(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow P^1(\mathbf{R})$ be a projective transformation and consider its graph
$$
\Gamma_\tau \subset P^1(\mathbf{R}) \times P^1(\mathbf{R})
$$
i.e. $\Gamma_\tau=\{(X, Y): Y=\tau(X)\}$. Using the one-to-one correspondence between $P^1(\mathbf{R}) \times P^1(\mathbf{R})$ and a quadric surface in $P^3(\mathbf{R})$, show that $\Gamma_\tau$ is the intersection of the quadric surface with a plane.


My attempt:
Let $X=[x_0:x_1]$ and $Y=[y_0:y_1]$ be homogeneous coordinates of points $X,Y$ in $\mathbf{R}P^1$. Then $\tau$ is represented by an invertible linear transformation $T:\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}^2$ with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, where $ad-bc\neq0$.
The one-to-one correspondence between $P^1(\mathbf{R}) \times P^1(\mathbf{R})$ and a quadric surface $X_0X_3=X_1X_2$ in $P^3(\mathbf{R})$, is given by the Segre embedding $\mathbf{R}P^1\times\mathbf{R}P^1\to\mathbf{R}P^3$: $([x_0:x_1],[y_0:y_1])\mapsto[x_0y_0:x_0y_1:x_1y_0:x_1y_1]=[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]$.
$\tau([x_0:x_1])=[ax_0+bx_1:cx_0+dx_1]$. So the graph of $\tau$ is the set of points $(X,Y)$ such that $(ax_0+bx_1)y_1=(cx_0+dx_1)y_0$.
This is the equation of a plane $aX_1+bX_3=cX_0+dX_2$ in $\mathbf{R}P^3$.
So the intersection of this plane and this quadric surface contains $\Gamma_\tau$.
But how can we show the other inclusion: $\Gamma_\tau$ contains the intersection of this plane and this quadric surface? Thanks.

You showed that for any choice of $[x_0,x_1]$ the point of the graph
$$
([x_0,x_1],[ax_0+bx_1, cx_0+dx_1])
$$
belongs to the intersection
$$
X_0X_3=X_1X_2;\qquad aX_1+bX_3=cX_0+dX_2\quad (1)
$$
Suppose now you are given a point in the intersection with homogeneous coordinates $[X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3]$. Observe first that for any values of $x_0$ and $x_1$, the values
$$
X_0=x_0(ax_0+bx_1),\quad X_1=x_0(cx_0+dx_1),\quad X_2=x_1(ax_0+bx_1),\quad X_3=x_1(cx_0+dx_1)
$$
formally satisfies the system $(1)$.
We need to prove that it is possible to choose $x_0$ and $x_1$, not both of them zero, in such a way that
$$
x_0(ax_0+bx_1):x_0(cx_0+dx_1):x_1(ax_0+bx_1):x_1(cx_0+dx_1)=X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3\qquad (2)
$$
First, assume none of the $X_i$ is zero. Then the condition
$$
x_0(ax_0+bx_1):x_0(cx_0+dx_1)=X_0:X_1
$$
is satisfied by setting
$$
ax_0+bx_1=X_0;\qquad cx_0+dx_1=X_1.
$$
The latter system has a unique solution given that the matrix $(a\,\,b/c\,\,d)$ is not singular. Moreover, $x_0\neq 0$, because otherwise we would have $X_0/X_1=b/d$ and, using the first equation in the system $(1)$, $X_2/X_3=b/d$. But then the second equation in $(1)$ implies $aX_1=cX_0$ and therefore $a/c=b/d$, a contradiction.
The rest of the conditions in $(2)$ are automatically satisfied for the values of $x_0$ and $x_1$ we just found, given that $X_0$ and $X_1$ uniquely determine $X_2$ and $X_3$ via the system $(1)$, as a consequence of $X_0/X_1\neq b/d$ and the non-singularity of the matrix $(a\,\,b/c\,\,d)$.
Next, we consider the situation when some $X_i$ are zero. If, say, $X_0=0$, by the first equation in $(1)$ we should have either $X_1=0$ or $X_2=0$. We cannot have three of them equal to zero because the second equation in $(1)$ would imply that all of them are zero, impossible. Assume then $X_0=0, X_1=0$.
Then $bX_3=dX_2$ and both $b$ and $d$ must be non-zero, since they cannot be both zero and $X_2\neq 0$, $X_3\neq 0$. Choose $x_0=0$ and $x_1\neq 0$ from $bx_1^2=X_2$ (or equivalently $dx_1^2=X_3$).
The above proves that any point satisfying $(1)$ is in the graph.
